# How to get a string form of BeautifulSoup NavigableString that keeps the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm processing a large data file in HTML format using Python's BeautifulSoup.

And I'm getting NavigableStrings which I need to unicode encode before printing out. If I take either the get_text() or .string from the NavigableString, it seems to strip out all the HTML tags from it.

On the other hand, NavigableString itself doesn't seem to have a .encode("utf-8") type option.

So how can I turn my NavigableString into an ordinary string without stripping the tags?

Comment: `str(string)` maybe?

Comment: Well, that (stripping the tags) is the point of a NavigableString: "A NavigableString is just like a Python Unicode string, except that it also supports some of the features described in Navigating the tree and Searching the tree." Do you want to keep the tags?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep the tags. But I also want to .encode the string.

Answer (score 3):

To print the HTML as text you just need to cast it to a string, then you can encode it in UTF-8 like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<body>
    <div>hello</div>
    </body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print str(soup).encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to get the original HTML code from a NavigableString, but **calling the `output_ready` method was a good enough alternative in my use case**.

Here is an example. There is a NavigableString `ns` that contains an angle bracket, three dots and another angle bracket. It comes from a HTML document where the brackets were encoded as HTML entities.

As you can see, printing `ns.text` outputs a decoded string. Calling `ns.output_ready()` outputs the string in the same form as in the original HTML document (in my case).

```
>>> print(ns.text)
<...>
>>> print(ns.output_ready())
&lt;...&gt;
```

What the `output_ready` method really does is encode HTML entities. The output is not necessarily the same as in the original HTML document, but it was good enough for me.

Documentation: https://pydocbrowser.github.io/beautifulsoup4/latest/bs4.element.NavigableString.html#output_ready